# Can objective c pointer be used to point to swift object instance

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, object

This may be a silly question, but I have a class I rewrote in swift that i am trying assign to a pointer in an objective c class. That is possible, correct?

The reason I haven't converted the other class yet is I am trying to piece meal the conversion of the classes.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to use an Objective-C class with a Swift class?  That's absolutely possible, just use a bridging header.  You can also use Swift with an Objective-C object.

Comment: It was using an objective c class with a swift class. I adjusted my question to help better describe my question.

Comment: You can't use a Swift class from Objective-C unless it is tagged with the `@objc` attribute, or it inherits from an Objective-C class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Especially this section:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122

Here is a quick example:

```
// A Swift class to be used in Objective C
// Note: it must inherit from NSObject, whether directly or not!
class SwiftClass : NSObject
{
    var i : Int32 = 333;

    // This function will be called from Objective C and passed a pointer to a 
    // SwiftClass instance allocated in Objective C.
    static func printSwiftClass( sc : SwiftClass)
    {
        print("The value of property i is \(sc.i)")
    }
}

// Call an Objective-C function that will use a pointer to SwiftClass
ClassObjC.staticFun()

// This goes into the bridging header, directly or indirectly.
// Needed to let Swift know about the ClassObjC class and its
// interface
@interface ClassObjC : NSObject

+(void)staticFun;

@end
```

And here is the implementation of our Objective-C class:

```
// This header is auto-generated by Xcode and has Swift definitions
// for use in Objective C
#import "cli_swift-Swift.h"

@implementation ClassObjC

+(void)staticFun
{
    // Create a SwiftClass instance
    SwiftClass *sc = [[SwiftClass alloc] init];
    // Set its i property
    sc.i = 444;
    // Call a Swift function to print the property i of the SwiftClass
    // instance we just created
    [SwiftClass printSwiftClass:sc];
}

@end
```